# If you build around 75% of a house on a neighboring lot, who has permission to live in that house?

Tags: united-states, property, civil, equity

I'm sure that long ago I read something about a building built where a percentage of that building was on the footprint of a neighboring lot, but I'm struggling to find information about the topic.

How much say could a plaintiff have to eject someone living in a house that is at least three quarters NOT on the property of the plaintiff?

Comment: please explain to me how you manage to put 75% of the 2D footprint of a 3D object *onto* or *into* a 1D  line.

Comment: And wouldn't the builder need permission to build on someone else's land (i.e. *within the propertyline*)? The answer may lie it the deeds.

Comment: I assume this happens by mistake, the builder not having taken a proper survey

Comment: Owner hasn't been around for a while. Builder was a caretaker for property not caring about lines.

Comment: Online county map shows property lines and it shows that building is mostly within neighboring property.

Answer (score 2):

If Alice builds (or hires someone to build) a building, whether house, shed pavalion, gazebo, garage, or whatever, so that part of its footprint is on Bob's proprty, Bob can demand that Alice remove that portion, and a court will enforce that demand. Bob can contract with Alice, in return for not enforcing such a demand, that he have access to, or part ownership of, the building. (Or anything else he and Alice agree on.)

Something like this occurs with a pavilion in the story "The Ambassador from Wall Street" by [Louis Auchincloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Auchincloss), part of the collection *Powers of Attorney*.

Comment: If the intrusion is minimal and unintentional, a court invoked prior to the adverse possession deadline will order the land sold to the encroacher for FMV as an equitable remedy in most case (if not defense to the equitable relief is present), but not in the circumstances of the OP.

Comment: In the Uk, one adverse party quite recently paid a six digit sum to their lawyers, another six digit sum for the neighbour’s lawyers, and a six digit sum to have their building restored to the original size. Plus the original building cost.